# tf message_filters and child_frame_id

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, frame-id, message-filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Message filters are handy when you want to only fire callbacks if a transform is available for the data contained therein. The user sets the target frame_id, and presumably the source frame_id is derived from the message's header.

However, nav_msgs/Odometry messages contain both pose and twist data, with the former being in the message header's frame_id, and the latter being in the message's child_frame_id. Even if no transform exists for the pose data, there may be a transform for the twist data. I can't just set up another filter with the target child_frame_id, as the message filter will then look for a transform from the odometry message's frame_id (i.e., pose data frame) to the target child_frame_id, which will probably not make any sense.

Do I have any recourse here? Clearly, I can just fire all the callbacks and check for the transform availability myself, but I'm guessing I'm going to lose some efficiency that way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193946/tf-message_filters-and-child_frame_id/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13689 on 2014-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-10-01**:
I already break each odometry message into a pose message and a twist message and then manually call their callbacks; I suppose I can manually add those sub-messages to their respective message filters instead. Still, if there's a cleaner way, I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this case I'd suggest that you create two tf::MessageFIlters, one for each datatype and callback. Then when you recieve the aggregate message, create the individual messages and add them to the respective MessageFilter.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-10-01**:
Doing exactly that. Thanks!